# Automating Facebook reauthorization for multiple users on a single device

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, oauth, single-sign-on

We are building an iPhone application that requires Facebook to signup. We would like to do two things after a user has created an account, and then logs out of our application. We are working within the constraints of four primary assumptions.

A. User(s) have already signed up and their FB token(s) are stored on the device

B. There may be more than one user that signs up or logs in from a single device. In which case multiple tokens may be stored.

C. No user is logged in to our app currently

D. It is unclear which user is logged into the Facebook app at this time

With these assumptions, we have two questions:

1. How do we match the correct stored token with the person currently logged into Facebook on the device?
2. How do we skip the prompt, "You have already authorized..." that requires an "okay" before returning to the app?

Code examples would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Given {C.} this seems nearly impossible. If a user is logged into your app and has already approved the app, you could probably just store the oauth token internally in a database tied to the user on your system. However if the user is anonymous and you have multiple tokens associated with multiple users, I don't believe there is a way to infer the correct token without potential security risks { key=user_name, value=assoc_oauth_token }... Maybe I'm just mis-understanding the question.

Answer (score 0):

So if I understood correctly, you just want to achieve multi-facebook-user on your single device and ability to swap between them without reauthenticating?

Here are the steps I think you could follow to do this:

1. User signs in
2. Store their profile_pic + facebook uid + access_token + name in some kind of persistent storage, you could simply store this in `NSUserDefaults` but there are ways to use more secured Keychain storage for access_token [here](http://mobiledevelopertips.com/core-services/using-keychain-to-store-username-and-password.html)
3. Set this set of key/value pair as 'active'
4. When user signs out, the app doesn't actually sign the user out of Facebook, but just clear the active key/value pair
5. Present the users who logged in by reading back the values you stored (names + profile pic)
6. User tap on one profile, set this as active or authenticate a new profile and repeat step

**Important Note:** you have to be very careful now because traditionally it was possible to get a non-expiring access token with `offline_access` permission. But [starting July 2012](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/), this is deprecated and the token *will* expire. So you need to [extend the token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/#extend_token) everytime the user profile is selected